# using mapstruct how to map an object to a list of objects with spring component mappers

Tags: mapstruct

I am trying to map an object A to a list of object B.
I have a mapper which maps from object A to object B.

I have tried a number of different ways for example
Trying to create a list with one object A using 'expressions'
And 'qualifiedByName' but this does not work because I think 
when you use expressions/qualifiedByName you can not use 
Custom mappers ( I could be wrong here ?)

I also tried to call the mapper from the @aftermapper method using 
The ‘mappers.getMapper’ to get a handle on the target mapper
But I found that the spring beans used in the mapper 
Where not being populated. Mapping in the aftermapping makes
Sense in that I can call the target mapper with the source
And then add the target to the list. So I am hoping that there 
is another Way to get a handle on the mapper component from my mapper.

All my mappers use 
   `@Mapper(componentModel="spring",`

All suggestions are welcome
Below is an code sample showing the problem.

Regards,
Declan

```
    // SPECIESTOLOGSPECY.JAVA
    // From this mapper I want to call SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi mapper
    // to map ‘species’ to ‘logdeclarations’ which is a list of logdeclaration
    // you can see want I am trying to do in the aftermapping method
    // where I map species to logdeclaration and then put this into a list
    // unfortunately I need other mapping components (ConfigMapperFromCode & SpecyToFishDeclarationMapperApi)
    // to be autowired into  SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi and this is not happening.
    // is there another way to get a handle to the spring managed 
    // SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi mapper ?

     @Mapper(componentModel="spring",
     uses = {
         ConfigMapperFromCode.class, 
         GeoInfoMapper.class,
         SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi.class
            })
     public interface SpeciesToLogSpecy {
     SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi.class);

@Mappings(
        {
            @Mapping(target="createdate", expression = "java(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()))"),
            @Mapping(target="speciesid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "speciesIdFromCodeAsDecimal"},  source = "species.speciesCode"),
            @Mapping(target="unitweight", constant = "1"),
            @Mapping(target = "inactiveind", constant = "N"),
            @Mapping(target = "unitdefaultind", constant = "Y"),
            @Mapping(target = "sectiontypeid", expression = "java(new BigDecimal(ie.gov.agriculture.fisheries.logsheet.mapping.constants.MappingConstants.LOG_SPECIES_SECTION_TYPE_SHEETDECLARATION))"),
            @Mapping(target = "unituomid", expression = "java(new BigDecimal(ie.gov.agriculture.fisheries.logsheet.mapping.constants.MappingConstants.LOGSHEET_CATCHUNITS_KG))"),
            @Mapping(target="catchtypeid",  qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "returnCatchTypeId"},  source = "species.spType"),
            @Mapping(target="legalfishsizetypeid",  qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "legalFishSizeTypeIdFromCode"},  source = "species.fishSizeClass"),
            @Mapping(target="presenttypeid",  qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "presentationTypeIdFromCode"},  source = "species.presentation.presentationType"),
            //@Mapping(target="logdeclarations", source = "species")                
        }           
         )
Logspecy speciesToLogspecy(Species species, @Context ExtraFields extraFields);


    @AfterMapping
    default void afterMap(@MappingTarget Logspecy logspecy, @Context ExtraFields extraFields){
    Logdeclaration logDeclaration = MAPPER.SpeciesToLogDeclarations(species, extraFields);

    List<Logdeclaration> logdeclarations = new ArrayList<Logdeclaration>(); 
    logdeclarations.add(logDeclaration);
    logSpecy.setLogdeclarations(logdeclarations);    
    {




    // SPECYTOLOGDECLARATIONMAPPERAPI.JAVA



    @Mapper(componentModel="spring",
    uses = {
        ConfigMapperFromCode.class,
        SpecyToFishDeclarationMapperApi.class       
        }    
)
public interface SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi {


@Mappings(
        {
            @Mapping(target="createdate", expression = "java(java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()))"),              
            @Mapping(target="geartypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "gearIdFromCode"},  source = "species.gearType"),
            @Mapping(target="fishcount", source = "species.qty"),
            @Mapping(target = "inactiveind", constant = "N"),
            @Mapping(target="packagetypeid", qualifiedByName={"ConfigMapperFromCode", "packagingTypeIdFromCode"},  source = "species.presentation.packaging"),
            @Mapping(target="packagecount", source = "species.presentation.pkgunit"),
            @Mapping(target="avgpackageweight", source = "species.presentation.pkgUnitWeight"),
            @Mapping(target="conversionfactor", source = "species.presentation.convFactor"),
            @Mapping(target="fishdeclaration", source = "species.geoInfo")              
        }           
        )
Logdeclaration SpeciesToLogDeclarations (Species species, @Context ExtraFields extraFields);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to map `Species` to `List<Logdeclaration>` and MapStruct cannot find such mapping method. In order to make it work you can add the following methods to your `SpecyToLogDeclarationMapperApi`:

```java
default List<Logdeclaration> SpeciesToLogDeclarationsToList(Species species, @Context ExtraFields extraFields) {
    if ( species == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    Logdeclaration logDeclaration = SpeciesToLogDeclarations(species, extraFields);

    List<Logdeclaration> logdeclarations = new ArrayList<Logdeclaration>();
    logdeclarations.add(logDeclaration);
    return logdeclarations;
}
```

This are some additional things, that I think you can do to improve your code and use MapStruct "more correctly":

- You will need to remove the usage of `Mappers#getMapper(Class)` when the component model is not the `default`
- If you don't want to use FQN in your expressions, you can use `Mapper#imports` and MapStruct will import them in the implementation.
- When you have a single source parameter you don't have to use it's name in the mapping

e.g.

```
@Mapping(target="fishcount", source = "species.qty")
```

can be

```
@Mapping(target="fishcount", source = "qty")
```